# Awstats shows blank page

Tags: awstats

On Windows Server 2008... since installing an ASP.Net application on the site, Awstats (6.5) produces error pages. So I moved the cgi-bin etc to a different site so that it could use Net 2.0 and the script seems to be running ok again, except that visiting http://stats.example.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl produces a blank page.

The stats are supposed to be for example.com, so I am wondering if running the script from a different site, stats.example.com, even though configured for example.com, is failing some security check?

How to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the site.com.conf file and look for this line:

```
UseFramesWhenCGI=1
```

Change to not use frames...

```
UseFramesWhenCGI=0
```